# Emacs doesn't see agda when launched from an .sh script

Tags: bash, emacs, sh, agda, agda-mode

I made an `.sh` script with the following code

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/Projects/Agda\ projects/
emacs
```

But whenever I launch it I get the following error

```
File is missing: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, /bin/bash: agda-mode: command not found


To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

In this session agda's executable isn't on the `PATH` and `PATH` differs from what I have in `~/.bashrc`

I have tried installing `exec-path-from-shell` but that didn't solve the problem.

Launching `emacs` from `konsole` manually works flawlessly for some reason.

Debug trace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "/bin/bash: agda-mode: command not found\n")
  load("/bin/bash: agda-mode: command not found\n" nil nil t)
  load-file("/bin/bash: agda-mode: command not found\n")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/bratjuuc/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 470
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/bratjuuc/.emacs" "/home/bratjuuc/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1e0f4d>)()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

How do I launch `emacs` with `agda-mode` from an .sh script?

Comment: [emacs.se] would be a better place to ask this.

Comment: There's now a dedicated StackExchange site for [proof assistants](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com). Maybe that's even more suitable than Emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suggesting to add environment context to your script.

```
#!/bin/sh
. ~/.profile
cd ~/Projects/Agda\ projects/
emacs
```